# Evaluating a command in bash pipe but return value is wrong

Tags: sed, grep, zsh, piping, wc

```
counter=$( grep -n 'ABC' $1 | sed 's/:[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*;//' > $2 | wc -l );

echo $counter; #Output is 0?
```

the value of the counter should be the output of `wc -l` right? Why do I find it to be zero? I using *zsh*. If I execute the command directly I face no problem. Is it something to do with `wc` that it prints something but return something else? How do I do this correctly.

---

What I'm doing?

I'm printing line numbers using grep and using sed I'm removing the content of the line and using wc I'm counting the number of lines the output has.

---

Edit:

Directly on shell
[image: fdgs]

---

Ulterior motive:

My ulterior motive is to split a file. To do that I'm identifying some line numbers. So, using grep I'm looking for certain text (as you can see it is `SET SCHEMA`, in the picture). I don't want the content of the lines just line numbers, so I cut out the lines by identifying the start and end. Using wc -l I'm counting lines.

Comment: You're redirecting the output of `sed` to a file, so `wc` will always count 0 lines.

Comment: Why is it that I get answer when I runt this directly in bash

Comment: What do you mean? I'm telling you to remove the redirection: `counter=$( grep -n 'ABC' $1 | sed 's/:[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*;//' | wc -l );` (remove the `> $2` of the `sed` command).

Comment: It worked. But, please check the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't redirect the output both to a pipe and also to a file at the same time directly. To do that you can use the `tee` command:

```
... | sed 's/:[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*;//' | tee "$2" | ...
```

Comment: I don't understand why redirecting worked directly on terminal then?

Comment: If you just redirect the command (without tee), you shouldn't see any output

Comment: There is no redirect in the screenshot

Comment: @TarunMaganti: That should never happen... Are you sure you are using `bash`?

Comment: I mentioned `zsh` in question. Could that be the reason?

Comment: @TarunMaganti: Ah, I missed that, I don't have `zsh` available to test, so I can't tell, but `tee` should work on all shells

Comment: I just check on bash. It didn't work. temp link - https://ibb.co/cqhzGQ

Comment: `zsh` has an option (`MULTIOS`) that allows multiple redirections on a single command; it's like running an implicit `tee`.

Comment: @chepner: That's nice to know, when I saw the question it was wrongly tagged [bash] instead of [zsh]. It looks like zsh has lots of nice features, but with bash being so ubiquitous, is it worth learning another shell?

Comment: `zsh` was designed primarily to make interactive use more productive, and you can (almost) treat it as a superset of `bash` for that use.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
counter=$( grep -n 'ABC' $1 | sed 's/:[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*;//' | wc -l );

echo $counter; #Output is 0?
```

What do want to reach with the sed command?

You also could use this:

```
counter=$( grep -n 'ABC' $1 | wc -l );
```

This command:

```
grep -n 'ABC' $1
```

get the following output:

```
1:ABC 3:ABC
```

Now you want count the occurrence of 'ABC'. In this case 2, right ?

A simple grep with wc do the job or am i wrong ?

```
grep -n 'ABC' $1 | wc -l
```

[wc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wc) manpage:

-l, --lines
print the newline counts

Comment: As you can see, I using sed command to print the line number into a file.

Comment: Could you please tell me what your result exactly should be? I will try to help you.